# pandas: replace non-empty rows in a column with a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace

I have a dataframe like the following (but longer) with some rows containing None values:

```
data = {'first Column':  ['she is', 'they are',NaN,'we are',NaN],
    'second Column ': ['my', 'her',NaN,'his',NaN],
    'third column': ['friend', 'brothers',NaN,'sisters',NaN]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['first Column','second Column','third column])
```

my_list= ['gold','silver','bronze']

I would like to replace every row in the 'third column' with a list if it does not contain none value, like this :

```
  desired output:
     first column   second column   third column
  0  she is          my             ['gold','silver','bronze']
  1  they are        her            ['gold','silver','bronze']
  2  NaN             NaN            NaN
  3  we are          his            ['gold','silver','bronze']
  4  NaN             NaN            NaN
```

I have tried np.where, but it does not select the desired rows

```
   np.where(df.loc[df['third column'] != 'NaN', [','.join(my_list)], df['third column']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['third column'].notna(),'third column']=[my_list]
```

Result:

```
  first Column second Column             third column
0       she is             my  [gold, silver, bronze]
1     they are            her  [gold, silver, bronze]
2          NaN            NaN                     NaN
3       we are            his  [gold, silver, bronze]
4          NaN            NaN                     NaN
```

PS: if you specifiy `data` as a dict with column names you don't need the `columns` argument in the dataframe constructor.